# Can we assume 230VAC in 3 phase system between phase and neutral?

Tags: three-phase, power-meter, power-measurement

If all devices connected to a 400V 3 phase power system are balanced and have a perfect power factor, can we assume the voltage between each phase and neutral is 230V?

Why: I want to measure real power consumption of a 3 phase air conditioner, but can only use current clamps. If I can make the assumption that the voltages are 230V, then I would measure each phase separately and just add up the kWh together.

Comment: If you are connected to a real city grid the voltage will vary, if you are ok with that as an inaccuracy of your measurement you can assume the nominal grid voltage.

Comment: Yes, I'm ok with that inaccuracy.

If I measured the voltage in a standard outlet, could I assume that in most cases it would be the same as in the 3 phase system?

Comment: If you have the voltage of an outlet of the same grid, you can assume that at least that phase has the same voltage at your AC unit, but the other phases may be a bit off, though in most bigger grids not that much

Comment: Great, this answers my question. Do you want to move it into the answer?

Comment: You can not assume that the air conditioner has a perfect power factor. Any measurement of power must be done with a wattmeter connected to read both voltage and current. You could assume the power factor is between 0.7 and 0.95.

Comment: @CharlesCowie To say that a measurement must be done by measuring both voltage and current, you're forgetting to ask the key questions such as - what is the purpose of the measurement, what is the acceptable error, what are available resources etc.
The 5% error on each phase when not measuring voltage is acceptable for me, so current measurement is sufficient.

Also, for my scenario it is a valid assumption, because I'll be directly relating the consumption to a power bill, and reactive power is not billed.

Comment: The current measurement is not sufficient unless you don't care about the additional 5 to 30% error caused by assuming 1.0 power factor. If the purpose requires true power rather than volt-amperes, you either have the resources to measure it or you don't. I am telling you what you need.

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated the question.

Comment: airconditioning units do not have perfect power factor

Comment: Assuming the air conditioner has a perfect power factor means your calculated power is 5 to 30 percent high plus or minus the 5% line voltage variation.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't realize that the power I'm getting right now is apparent... I'll take a look into the power factors